# Firebase Cloud Messaging Pod install problems - RNFIRMessaging.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following the instructions to add Firebase FCM messaging to my react native application using this library: https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

I'm following it's instructions and installed the library, ran react-native link, and pod installed but I'm getting the error `RNFIRMessaging.h file not found`

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"
```

I see that the pod installed the library project - do I need to link it somehow or set a reference to it using xcode?

I'm not sure how to check that pod references are set up correctly in XCode.

[image]

Comment: Seems like this issue might be related https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/21 - so it might be missing a header search path